# Is it good practice to write logs into JSON format?

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a java application with logback. I think about writing logs directly in JSON format and send to ELK stack instead of plain and parsing its with logstash. Is that a good practice?

Comment: we do, works for us - this is probably heading towards an opinion based question though...

Comment: How do you process logs? Do you keep its in Elastic?

Comment: Yep - we have a base class for event logging and then subclass it for specific log messages.  These get serialised to json into the log file, filebeat sends to logstash which applies a few rules here and there on certain messages, but for the most part forwards straight to elastic to store as-is